# mongodb Aggregate query from Python

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

Am new to this mongodb query from python.

I want to run a aggregate query in mongodb using pymongo.

So I have tried in nosqlbooster as well.

but also want to try in python as well. And framed below pattern.

This works well in sqlbooster sw but not in Python.

```
    query=
           (
  [
  {
     "$match":{
        "ts":{
           "$gte":1588157100000,
           "$lt":1588158000000
        },
        "a":{
           "$gt":0
        },
        "s":{
           "$gt":0
        },
        "d":{
           "$gt":0
        }
     }
  },
  {
     "$group":{
        "_id":1,
        "aAvg":{
           "$avg":"$a"
        },
        "sAvg":{
           "$avg":"$s"
        },
        "dAvg":{
           "$avg":"$d"
        },
        "aMax":{
           "$max":"$a"
        },
        "sMax":{
           "$max":"$s"
        },
        "dMax":{
           "$max":"$d"
        },
        "aMin":{
           "$min":"$a"
        },
        "sMin":{
           "$min":"$s"
        },
        "dMin":{
           "$min":"$d"
        }
     }
  },
  {
     "$project":{
        "_id":1,
        "aAvg":1,
        "sAvg":1,
        "dAvg":1,
        "aMax":1,
        "sMax":1,
        "dMax":1,
        "aMin":1,
        "sMin":1,
        "dMin":1
     }
  }
 ]);


  document = db.WL.aggregate(query)
  for i in document:
     print(i)
```

And as mentioned, this doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above one returns the value, once the outer braces get removed .